# Level designer responsible for q3dm17

Tags: quake-3

I'd like to know the author (or authors) of a Quake 3 FFA map called "[The Longest Yard](http://quake.wikia.com/wiki/Q3DM17:_The_Longest_Yard)" (q3dm17).

[image: The Longest Yard]

Comment: Found this somewatish related info reading about [Levelord](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_Gray_(game_designer)) on Wikipedia: *He created the first suspended platform, aka "void", deathmatch called HIPDM1 or "The Edge of Oblivion" for the Quake add-on pack Scourge of Armagon. This "islands in space" design of this multiplayer map became a staple in Quake III Arena and many other deathmatch games.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is not 100% sure info about who exactly did it, though we can make a list of level designers, who worked on the game. This map is one of the original maps released by id Software in 1999. As stated in the credits [here](https://youtu.be/Ff0FIkXrL2A?t=3m14s), these level designers are:

- Christian Antkow
- Paul Jaquays
- Tim Willits

They were helped by:

- Kaai Cluney
- Brandon James

[The very same question was asked on Quora.com](https://www.quora.com/Quake-series-Who-was-the-level-designer-for-q3dm17), and it has an answer: Brandon James, which is also on the previous list above.

When searching info about Brandon "KillMe" James, nothing is found about which maps did he worked on. Also, he left id Software during the development of Quake 3, leaving a number of unfinished maps, as stated [here](https://www.bluesnews.com/s/3410/killme-leaves-id) and [here](http://www.shacknews.com/article/181/more-on-bjames-id-departure).

> How will this affect Quake 3? Brandon James's incomplete maps and
>   other responsibilities will be divided up between us.

Comment: Normally, I wouldn't trust a Quora.com answer, but this one seems signed by [Timothee Besset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timothee_Besset) himself (a former id employee) so... :)